# Aligning avatar and text within a div

Tags: html, css

I have this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bnqksu4y/

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2><i></i>Support Forum</h2>
<div>
    <a href="https://www.website.co.uk/support-forums/users/chuckie/">
    <img alt="" height="40" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/e8ab00a7baa7aee84ab234bfe219343e?s=40&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" srcset="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/e8ab00a7baa7aee84ab234bfe219343e?s=80&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x" width="40"></a>
    <h4>
    <a href="https://www.website.co.uk/support-forums/users/chuckie/">
    Andrew Truckle</a></h4>
    <a href="https://www.website.co.uk/logout/">
    Log Out</a> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, I want the **name** to show to the **right** of the **avatar**. And **Log Out** should show underneath.

If I use a `float:left` on the `img` and `h4` objects then then everything shows side by side, including **Log Out** which is not what I want.

How to fix?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/nmj5v7ec/

Comment: using css you can display elements block, inline, inline-block, ... inline elements can be in one line, block elements not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2><i></i>Support Forum</h2>
<div>
    <a href="https://www.website.co.uk/support-forums/users/chuckie/">
    <img alt="" height="40" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/e8ab00a7baa7aee84ab234bfe219343e?s=40&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" srcset="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/e8ab00a7baa7aee84ab234bfe219343e?s=80&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x" width="40"></a>
    <h4 style="display:inline">
    <a href="https://www.website.co.uk/support-forums/users/chuckie/">
    Andrew Truckle</a></h4>
    <br>
    <a href="https://www.website.co.uk/logout/">
    Log Out</a> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, I just changed `<h4>` to `<h4 style="display:inline">`

Is it something like this? or something different?

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/n8Lrg1d6/

Comment: Thanks. Are you able to add a fiddle to your answer? Like the one provided in a comment by Jarlik Stepsto?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to get the solution without modifying the HTML. Assuming that you do not have any control on HTML part. Below is the CSS which helps you align your tags.

But if you can modify your HTML, I would suggest that you add some class or id and add the below CSS to respective selector instead of applying globally.

**Solution:**

```css
h4, img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a[href*="logout"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2><i></i>Support Forum</h2>
<div>
    <a href="https://www.website.co.uk/support-forums/users/chuckie/">
      <img alt="" height="40" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/e8ab00a7baa7aee84ab234bfe219343e?s=40&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" srcset="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/e8ab00a7baa7aee84ab234bfe219343e?s=80&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x" width="40">
    </a>
    <h4>
      <a href="https://www.website.co.uk/support-forums/users/chuckie/">
    Andrew Truckle</a>
    </h4>
    <a href="https://www.website.co.uk/logout/">
    Log Out</a> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
  <h2><i></i>Support Forum</h2>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.website.co.uk/support-forums/users/chuckie/">
        <p> <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/e8ab00a7baa7aee84ab234bfe219343e?s=40&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g"
                alt="" height="40"> <a href="https://www.website.co.uk/support-forums/users/chuckie/">
                Andrew Truckle</a>.</p>
        <a href="https://www.website.co.uk/logout/">Log Out</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Easiest is to just insert content into the tags : `<p> text, image, link... </p>`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can’t change the HTML. But the final syntax has classes so I can use CSS and the existing answers to style it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

First put the anchor tag of the **Log Out** link outside and below the **div tag**. because **avatar**, **name** and **log out** are sibling and children of div so you can't use use float and flex box to layout **avator**, **name** respectively and **log out** beneath them the. you can only layout using with CSS relative and absolute positioning

try this;

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2><i></i>Support Forum</h2>
    <div>
        <a href="https://www.website.co.uk/support-forums/users/chuckie/">
        <img alt="" height="40" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/e8ab00a7baa7aee84ab234bfe219343e?s=40&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" srcset="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/e8ab00a7baa7aee84ab234bfe219343e?s=80&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x" width="40">
        </a>
        <h4>
        <a href="https://www.website.co.uk/support-forums/users/chuckie/">
        Andrew Truckle</a>
       </h4>
    </div> 
    <a href="https://www.website.co.uk/logout/">Log Out</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

```
html body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body div{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can’t change the HTML. But the final syntax has classes so I can use CSS and the existing answers to style it as needed.